# Is the AppID Prefix Sensitive Information?

Tags: ios

I am needing to place the AppID Prefix string into my application source code to enable a Keychain Access Group. My project is hosted on GitHub. Is this AppID Prefix value sensitive, private information that should not be committed to source control or is it ok to share it with the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That shouldn't be a problem, it is [not private information](http://erik.io/blog/2014/10/10/vulnerability-apple-portal-compromised-keychain-access-groups/):

> App IDs and App ID prefixes are not secret.

The [AppID Prefix](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AppID.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH64-SW1) (a.k.a. Bundle Seed ID a.k.a. Team ID) is associated with a provisioning profile which is linked to you or your team. A malicious developer is not able to create provisioning profiles using AppIDs not belonging to him or her, it will not pass verification by Apple. (note: there used to be [a vulnerability](http://erik.io/blog/2014/10/10/vulnerability-apple-portal-compromised-keychain-access-groups/) in the online provisioning portal where it *was* possible to use other people's IDs, but that has been fixed somewhere in 2014)